# UFT 12.02 integration with TFS

Tags: hp-uft, tfs

I am looking for UFT and TFS integration (Run test from TFS like we did with HPQC) I search on google but no help . If anyone know how to do this please let me know steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will happen because HP has their own test management tool and don't seem to want to support others.